# Inconsistancy with knockout and mapping .toJS helper methods

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a view model and it has some existing properties.

```
model.prop1 = ko.observable("");
model.prop2 = ko.observable("");
```

I then map some data on to this model that will update the value of prop1.

```
var data = {prop1: 'blah'};
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, model);
```

I now have some inconsistency when I call `ko.toJS` and `ko.mapping.toJS`

with `ko.toJS` it is serialising the model as expected to this:

```
[object Object] {
  model: [object Object] {
    __ko_mapping__: [object Object] { ... },
    prop1: "blah",
    prop2: ""
  }
}
```

I have used the mapping plug-in so it has some superfluous data (**ko_mapping**) that I don't want.

As such I use `ko.mapping.toJS`, however this is not serialising all of the properties... only the ones that have been mapped.
It was my understanding that this would serialise everything as `ko.toJS` would?

```
[object Object] {
  model: [object Object] {
    prop1: "blah"
  }
}
```

Is this expected behaviour or have I found a bug?

JSBin : https://jsbin.com/jupemoneri/6/edit?js,console

Comment: Short answer, if you're going to use the mapping plugin to map your model, you need to use the mapping plugin to unmap it. There's a lot of metadata that the plugin needs to be able to work and a lot of that is stored using special properties on the object not meant to be used. Vanilla knockout is unaware of this so it will just treat the metadata like normal data.

Comment: I only want to use the mapping plugin for parts of my model. In my real example i have an `isEditing` observable flag. I don't want to send this down from via my data as it's not stored or part of my domain. That said i have a need to know it's value when I call .toJS on the whole thing.

Comment: @4imble you should answer your question with your delete comment on his answer because what you just described is absolutely the answer to your (and my) issue. The below answer does not address things like what you're describing where you need to add functions that return things you want to serialize after the mapping. thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1):

What you're explaining is the normal behavior of the mapper, and it has an explanation: when you bind a model to a view, only the existing observable properties will be bound. If you add new observable properties later, it will make no effect. The view will only be aware of the changes of the observbale properties that existed when it was bound.

So you need to modify the way in which you create the model the first time, so that it includes all the neccessary properties. The easiest way to do it is to use a javascript object that has all the properties, mix it with the object received from the server, and then convert it to model with `ko.mapping.fromJs`. Something like this:

```
// This is an empty object with all the excpected properties
var completeObject { a: null, b:null, c: null }; 

// "Mix in" the properties from the received, incompelte, object:
// An easy way to do it is using jquery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/
$.extend(completeObject,incompleteObjectFromServer);
```

// Create the view model using the mapping:
   var model = ko.mapping.fromJs(completeObject);

Once you do this, you'll get a "complete" model, with all the required properties converted into observable properties, so that they all can be bound to the view. When you use the mapping plugin later, these observable properties will be correctly updated, and the view will react to the changes.

Be aware that when you do the mapping, the model, apart from the observables, includes configuration created whne the object was originally mapped, and this configuration will be used in subsequent mappings, when you use `ko.mapping.fromJs()`.

There are other possible techniques to get the same results, like:

- receiving the incomplete object and including the missing properties "by hand"
- supplying options to the mapping, so that the object is created as expected. See the options section in [ko.mapping docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).
- modifying the server so that it returns a "complete" object. It doesn't matter if the rest of required properties are null or not, but they must be in the returned object.

NOTE: regarding `ko.toJS`, it has nothing to do with mapping: it simply retuns a new object in which the observable properties in the provided object are convertes into regular properties, and the rest of the properties are left as they are.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have a better understanding now however it still does not seem intuitive to me. I have not added any observables, i have simply mapped onto one of the existing ones (which supposedly should only update its value as it already exists). I find it strange that calling `ko.mapping.toJS` before doing the mapping will serialise all the properties, but doing it after will only serialise the mapped properties despite the original ones still being present and bindable from the view.

Comment: As I told you, using `ko.mapping.fromJS`, apart from creating a new object with observables, also stores some configuration, in the `__ko_mapping__` property. That's way makes 'ko.mapping.toJS' have a different behavior that `ko.toJS`. If you add some working code, I can give you a more precise information. Try adding a conde snippet or jsfiddel with further doubts.

Comment: There is a JSBin at the end of my question. I spoke to some of the other teams I work with and they get round this by deleting the `__ko_mapping__` property as soon as they map anything. They then use `ko.toJS` thereafter.